# how can i do such a slideshow? what customizations for Aythingslider?

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow, anythingslider

I need a slideshow with images that can be scrolled left or right, with only a certain number visible on the screen at one time.

< [image] [image] [image] >

I need to be able to add or remove images and images must contain links to open different new pages.

Can I use anythingslider? What customizations do I need?

Or, can you please recommend any other slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCarouselLite

Comment: this is useful.. i need some customization in it...  thanks for the reply.